# How to output Subscription name with Get-AzVM

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I am currently trying to output a list of VMs that are not compliant with a policy, all is working except I cant figure out how to output the subscription the VM lives in, since its not a property of Get-AzVm. If someone can please help me out, I am embarrassed I cant figure it out since it seems pretty simple. The current output will use the last subscription context for all the VMs, even though I have multiple subscriptions. Thanks a lot!

```
$vmsNotBackedUp = @()
$vms_results = @()
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

#set policy definition
$poldef = '013e242c-8828-4970-87b3-ab247555486d'


#Get VMs resource ID that are not backed up from Azure Policy, store in $resourceIDs variable

foreach ($sub in $subscriptions) {
Set-AzContext -Subscription $sub.Id



$resourceIDs =(Get-AzPolicyState -Filter "PolicyDefinitionName eq '$poldef' and ComplianceState eq 'NonCompliant'").ResourceId
$vmsNotBackedUp += Get-AzVM | Where-Object{$_.Id -in $resourceIDs}
$currentContext = $sub.Name
$currentContext
}


Write-Output("The Following VMs were not able to be backed up, may need investigation")

#$vmsNotBackedUp|Select-Object -Property Name,ResourceGroupName,Location

foreach ($vm in $vmsNotBackedUp) {
    $output_data = [PSCustomObject]@{
        vmName = $vm.Name
        ResourceGroup = $vm.ResourceGroupName
        vmLocation = $vm.Location
        vmOS = $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType
        vmSub = $currentContext
        
    }
    $vms_results += $output_data
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your scenario, but it seesm you have the subscription ID in `$sub.Id`.  You could add this as a property to the VMs you enumerate later.  Something like: `Get-AzVM | Where-Object{$_.Id -in $resourceIDs} | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Subscription' -Value $sub.id -PassThru`.

Comment: Yes. thank you so much. This worked perfectly, I did not know you can do this. Is there a way to mark this as an answer since its a comment?

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer so you can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the subscription ID in `$sub.Id`, you could add this as a property to the VMs you enumerate in your script. Something like this:

```
$vmsNotBackedUp += Get-AzVM |
    Where-Object{$_.Id -in $resourceIDs} |
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Subscription' -Value $sub.id -PassThru
```